# Deep Learning + ML + CV > Requirements.txt file

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, ubuntu-18.04

It would be really easy if I can save my environment in some file and can share it.  It will save time to replicate the environment.

P.S:
I have added solution below

Comment: Have a look at Anaconda environment.yml files: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment . They are a more complete solution than requirements.txt

Comment: Thank you...much needed this

Comment: Have a look at my [gist](https://gist.github.com/coree/4ab14341ff38c0f4c5c89eae7f1c051a) it is mainly based on this [requirement file](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/requirements.txt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time I create a virtual environment for machine learning project I just install this

```
jupyter==1.0.0
matplotlib==1.5.3
numexpr==2.6.1
numpy==1.12.0
pandas==0.19.1
Pillow==3.4.2
protobuf==3.0.0
psutil==5.0.0
scikit-learn==0.18.1
scipy==0.18.1
sympy==1.0
tensorflow>=1.6.0
opencv-python==4.1.0.25 # updated
```

save it as a `requirements.txt` file and install it using

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and you are ready to go.

Comment: P.S:  
1. [Conda:] (https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment)
2. [Docker: ] (https://www.docker.com/get-started)